# How do I make the hero image resize on width correctly?

Tags: html, css

Website noob here, please go easy on me.

I am currently developing a responsive website for a video game I voluntarily work for. For the most part the website is now very responsive, however I just have one more hurdle and for the life of me I cannot seem to figure it out.

The hero image, where the logo and background are the top of the page, doesn't resize correctly. It seems to resize on height rather than width, which is a problem as on mobile devices it seems to heavily cut both sides of the logo out.

Below is the HTML of the homepage alongside the CSS of the entire website. I have left out the CSS for the '@font-face' as the code is way too long to include here.

Since I am a big noob at website development, and I'm trying my best to learn new things as I go along, I haven't really been able to try many different things. I've dabbled in max-height and max-width, and I've also tried switching the values so that the width is 100% but the height is set to auto. Nothing seems to work. In fact, when I do the latter, the entire image just disappears.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Welcome! | Toontown's Funny Farm</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="The fan-made single-player sequel to Disney's Toontown Online.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Toontown,Toontown's,Funny,Farm,sequel,single,player,Disney,Online">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Welcome! | Toontown's Funny Farm" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="The fan-made single-player sequel to Disney's Toontown Online." />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Toontown's Funny Farm" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/home" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="toontownsfunnyfarm.com/images/header.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="images/icons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="images/icons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#993623">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#993623">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8b8cf6f445.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <script src="responsivenav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="hero-image"></div>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"><a href="https://www.toontownsfunnyfarm.com/" class="active">Home</a><a href="play">Play</a><a href="release-notes">Release Notes</a><a href="faq">FAQ</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="intro">Welcome to Funny Farm!</h1>
        <p class="center">Toontown's Funny Farm is a free-to-play fan-made single-player sequel to Disney's Toontown Online!
        <br>Want to know more? Head on over to the FAQ page!</p>
        <hr> </div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
        });
    </script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h1 class="center">Latest Announcements</h1>
            <ul class="announcements">
                <li>Welcome to our new and improved website! We've done some tweaking and cleaning up, and more updates will come to the site soon.</li>
                <li>Toontown's Funny Farm version 1.4.0 has been released! Go to the 'Play' page to download the NEW launcher and begin playing! Also, to find out more about what this update holds, head to the 'Release Notes' page.</li>
                <li>Join our Discord server to get more involved with our community. Meet other players, get announcements from the Toontown's Funny Farm team, and see exclusive sneak peeks of future content!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul class="rslides">
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/1.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/2.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/3.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/4.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/5.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/6.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/7.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/8.png" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="images/screenshots/9.png" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Follow us on Social Media!</h2> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/toontownsfunnyfarm"><i class="fab fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a> <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/TTsFunnyFarm"><i class="fab fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a> <a target="_blank" href="https://discord.gg/toontownsfunnyfarm"><i class="fab fa-fw fa-discord"></i></a>
            <p class="disclaimer">Toontown's Funny Farm is in no way affiliated with The Walt Disney Company and/or Disney Interactive.
                <br>Toontown's Funny Farm is a free-to-play video game created using publicly available information and assets, and does not generate revenue of any kind for its staff members.
                <p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(images/clouds.png);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}

.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin-top: 2.58vh
}

.rslides li {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%
}

.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: right
}

.rslides img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3vh
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Panton Black Caps';
    font-size: 4.13vh;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #cdcdcd
}

.intro {
    font-family: 'Panton Black Caps';
    font-size: 6.2vh;
    text-align: center
}

.subheading {
    padding-left: 13%;
    padding-right: 13%
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Panton Black Caps';
    font-size: 3.1vh;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000
}

p {
    font-family: 'Impress BT';
    font-size: 2.7vh;
    padding-left: 14%;
    padding-right: 14%;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #cdcdcd
}

hr {
    border: 0.155vh solid #696969;
    border-radius: 1.032vh;
    opacity: .15;
    margin: .5% 7%
}

ul {
    padding-left: 17%;
    padding-right: 17%
}

.announcements {
    padding-right: 6%
}

li {
    font-family: 'Impress BT';
    font-size: 2.69vh;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #cdcdcd
}

.center {
    text-align: center
}

.hero-image {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    height: 50%;
    width: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #993623;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Panton Black Caps';
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000;
    text-align: center
}

.topnav a {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.064vh 3.612vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3.302vh;
    transition: 0.055s
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ca723b;
    color: #fff
}

.topnav .active:hover {
    background-color: #ca723b;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none
}

.disclaimer {
    font-size: 1.858vh;
    padding-top: .5%;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000
}

.footer {
    background-color: #993623;
    color: #fff;
    padding: .2%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%
}

.fa-discord,
.fa-facebook,
.fa-twitter {
    font-size: 8.5vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000;
    transition: 0.075s
}

.fa-discord:hover {
    color: #7289da;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000044
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
    color: #1877f2;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #00005c
}

.fa-twitter:hover {
    color: #38a1f3;
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #000b5d
}

table {
    overflow-x:auto;
    font-family: 'Impress BT';
    font-size: 2.477vh;
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, .7);
    text-shadow: 0.1032vh 0.1032vh 0 #cdcdcd;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    border-collapse: collapse
}

td {
    padding: 1.2%;
    border: 0.3096vh solid #e6e6e6;
}

.dlwindows {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#39a3ed, #1280cf);
    width: 41.2797vh;
    color: #c4efff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #004582;
    font-family: Minnie;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 2.064vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer
}

.dlwindows:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#91cdf6, #76b7e5);
    color: #ddf6ff;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #6b93b7
}

.dlmacos {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8b0bd, #7f8793);
    width: 41.2797vh;
    color: #fefefe;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #646672;
    font-family: Minnie;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 2.064vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer
}

.dlmacos:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ced3d9, #b5b9c0);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #a5a6ad
}

.dllinux {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f3aa3d, #e88d1c);
    width: 41.2797vh;
    color: #ffdb9e;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #77351a;
    font-family: Minnie;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 2.064vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer
}

.dllinux:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f8ce8e, #f2bd7b);
    color: #ffeac7;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #b08a7a
}

.dlandroid {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a4c639, #8ab747);
    width: 41.2797vh;
    color: #e2efb8;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #4a6025;
    font-family: Minnie;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 2.064vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer
}

.dlandroid:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#cadd8c, #bbd594);
    color: #eef6d6;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #96a381
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%
    }
    .rslides {
        width: 88%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto
    }
    .rslides li {
        width: 100%
    }
    .rslides img {
        width: 100%
    }
    .announcements {
        padding-left: 12%;
        padding-right: 12%
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none
    }
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        display: block
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block
    }
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative
    }
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably have more luck getting help if you remove all the bits that are not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Check your background image positioning, if you use position: center and size: cover, most likely it will cut off the image on resizing, which is the expected behavior, you could use something like background-position: top left; if the logo is at the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit :**
As you wanted a responsive background image that resize like an `<img>`, I came up with a trick. It's not very proper as the image need to be loaded twice but it work.
You can see it in [this pen](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/JgOJXa).
To make it happen I used a container `div` with an image as background (like you did), and as a child I gave it the same image (`<img>`with `display: block`). Finally I hide this image with `visibility: hidden;` which *do not remove this image from the flow*. So the parent `div` do have content to wrap around and resize as the image, even though it's not visible.
*Edit 2* : For the "invisible image" I switched to a placeholder.com image as it's barely 4 bytes.
HTML

```
<div class="smallHeader">
  <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/1024x200' class='smallHeader- 
  image'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.smallHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/477/1024/200");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.smallHeader .smallHeader-image {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

**Original Post :**
Your are using your image as the background for an empty div.
So the value `auto` that you are using isn't adjusting with content (the background isn't content).
You can set the dimension of your `div` with `%`, `px`, `rem`.. etc and let the `background-size: cover` property do it's job.. but not `min-content`, `auto` ..etc as it is empty. `Auto` won't always compute as zero if there is no content but still i don't see the point here.
Here is [a pen](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/mNqEyZ) showing this.
Or alternatively you can use the image directly (`<img>`, without div) and apply some css like this (for exemple) :

```
img.hero-image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

W3Scools has a [small tuto](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp) on responsive images.
Note : To prevent a user easily copying, draging... an element you can add the following attributs to it

```
oncopy="return false;" oncut="return false;" onpaste="return false;" ondrop="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" onclick="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;"
```

Comment: Okay, so I've set my CSS to this if I'm understanding your comment correctly:

`.hero-image {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}`

This produces the same effect as before. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem of the image cropping incorrectly when I resize the window.

Here it is on my 1920x1080 monitor: http://prntscr.com/ooatvz

...and here it is when I've resized the window to roughly a mobile size: http://prntscr.com/ooau7f

Comment: To clarify, I don't really want to use the img tag method, as I don't want people to easily be able to right-click and save, or drag my image to save it. I want it to be considered a background image for that reason. Is there any way I can go about reproducing your fix but without resorting to the img tags?

Comment: You can use `stretch` instead of cover but it wont be pretty either. You can use @media queries and images of various sizes and keep cover. Or you can use the image tag and use  `<img src="thesource" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false"
ondrop="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" onclick="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;">` ... which maybe overkill. You can test it on the pen i linked in the post (on the purple square).

Comment: Alright, thank you. I think I'll just go with an img tag, wrap an anchor tag around it to link back to the homepage, and leave it as that. I've already done it and it fixes my issue. Not really in the way that I wanted it to, but this works visually. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of an unclickable div with a background purple (in my pen), i changed it to an image <img>

Comment: In the end I just used your img.hero-image CSS, and then used an anchor tag around the image in my HTML. Works exactly as expected. It's not the implementation I was hoping for, but it gets the job done. Thank you!

Comment: I found a trick to accomplish exactly what you wanted, and edited my post. I don't think it's very "proper" but it does the job

Comment: Thank you very much! I've switched to your new method. It's not very 'proper' of course but it does what I need it to. My website is also quite minimal and uses Cloudflare so it won't cause much of a performance issue or anything either. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your question, consider accepting it ;)

Comment: Done! Sorry about that - kinda new to Stack Overflow still haha. Thanks!